# how I can extract data between now and the end of the current date? Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, range

I need to extract the last hundred calls from now until the end of the current date

ejm:

`select * from call where create_at between >= yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 and <= yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59 limit 100`

how i can to extract the data between this range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current date, meaning today?

```
SELECT * from call
  WHERE create_at BETWEEN 'today' AND 'tomorrow'
  LIMIT 100
```

As mentioned, you probably also want to sort them, logically sorting them backwards would give the last 100

```
SELECT * from call
  WHERE create_at BETWEEN 'today' AND 'tomorrow'
  ORDER BY create_at desc
  LIMIT 100
```

You mentioned also "from now", so if you don't want already gone times, you can use (with order or not)

```
SELECT * from call
  WHERE create_at BETWEEN now() AND 'tomorrow'
  LIMIT 100
```

Comment: yes... the range is from this date until the end of the day

Comment: Note that a `limit` without an `order by` will pick the rows randomly. This might not be the "last hundred calls"

Comment: thank for your suggestion... i go to add the order by id or date